# Covariance of two independent random variables isnt it zero?

Tags: probability

We are given random variables X and Y independent and uniform on the interval [0,10]. Now I want to calculate Covariance of X and Y given that $X+Y<10$.

But isnt because of independence the covariance just zero?

Comment: You're not asked to calculate the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, rather the coditional covariance.  $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but conditioned on $X+Y<10$ they are not.